# Dynamic combobox in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, combobox

I have 4 tables: `metier` , `tache`, `technicien` and `tarificationtache`
with a many to many relationship and in the pricing table I have the following fields (`id`, `tache-id`, `tariff`)

In this code I display the list of `metier` then the list of `tache` link to the `metier` select and then the list of `tarificationtache` link to the `tache`select and now I display a table that contain the `technician` link to this `tarificationtache`

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts/master')
@section('content')
  <!--  jQuery -->
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var getTachesByMetierUrl = "{{url('/tachesbymetier')}}";
    var getAdresseByClientUrl = "{{url('/adressebyclient')}}";
    var getTarificationsByTacheUrl = "{{url('/tarificationsbytache')}}";
    var getTechniciensByTarificationUrl = " 
 {{url('/techniciensbytarification')}}";

function getAdresseByClient(val) {
        if(val.length>0) {
            var client_id = val;
            $.get(getAdresseByClientUrl+'/'+client_id,function(res) {
                var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
                $.each(res.adresses,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
 value="'+item.id+'">'+item.code_postal+'</option>';
                });
                $('#adresses').html(html);

            });
        }
    }


    function getTachesByMetier(val) {
        if(val.length>0) {
            var metier_id = val;
            $.get(getTachesByMetierUrl+'/'+metier_id,function(res) {
                var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
                $.each(res.taches,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
  value="'+item.id+'">'+item.libelle_tache+'</option>';
                });
                $('#taches').html(html);

            });
        }
    }
    function getTarificationsByTache(val) {

        if(val.length>0) {
            var tache_id = val;
            $.get(getTarificationsByTacheUrl+'/'+tache_id,function(res) {
                var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
                $.each(res.tarifications,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
 value="'+item.id+'">'+item.tarif+'</option>';
                });
                $('#tarifications').html(html);

            });
        }
    }

    function getTechniciensByTache(val) {
        if(val.length>0) {
            var tarification_id = val;
            $.get(getTechniciensByTacheUrl+'/'+tache_id,function(res) {
                var html = '<option value="">-Select-</option>' ;
                $.each(res.techniciens,function(index,item) {
                    html+='<option 
 value="'+item.id+'">'+item.technicien_id+'</option>';
                });
                $('#techniciens').html(html);

            });
        }
    }
</script>

@if(count($errors))
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors ->all() as $message)
                <li>{{$message}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
 @endif
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <h1>Ajout Intervention</h1>
        <form action=" {{url ('intervention')  }}" method="post">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="client">Client</label>
                <select onchange="getAdresseByClient(this.value)" 
 name="client_id" id="client" 
      class="form-control">
                    <option value="">-Select-</option>
                    @foreach($client as $t)
                        <option value="{{$t->id }}">
                            {{$t->user->nom}}
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">date intervention</label>

                <input class="form-control" type="date" id="example-date- 
 input" name 
     ="date_intervention" value="{{old('date_intervention')}}">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">description</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="description" class="form- 
 control"value=" 
      {{old('description')}}">
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">duree_prevu</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local"  name 
  ="duree_prevu" value=" 
    {{old('duree_prevu')}}">
            </div>
     <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Metier: </label>
                <select onchange="getTachesByMetier(this.value)" 
  style="width: 200px"   
      class="productm form-control" id="metiers">
               <option value="">-Select-</option>
                    @foreach($metiers as $t)
                        <option value="{{$t->id }}">
                            {{$t->libelle_metier}}
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>tache: </label>
                <select onchange="getTarificationsByTache(this.value)" 
 style="width: 200px" 
    class="productname form-control" name="tache" id="taches">
                <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>tarification: </label>
                <select onchange="getTechniciensByTache(this.value)" 
 style="width: 200px" 
      class="productname form-control" name="tarification_id" 
 id="tarifications">
                <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label>Technicien: </label>
                <select style="width: 200px" class="productname form- 
 control" 
      name="technicien_id" id="techniciens">
                <option value="">-Select-</option>
                </select>
            </div>
</div>
 </div>
</div>
 </div>
 </div>
<link 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap- 
    datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap- 
   datepicker.js"></script>
@endsection
```

route.php

```
Route::get('/techniciensbytache/{tache_id}',         
    'TechnicienController@getTechniciensByTache');
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: I would like to display out the list of technicians from the selection of tarification and tache

Comment: Another issue is when i select tarification i don't get technicians

Comment: This needs an [mcve] to be answerable.

Comment: Further to this, I notice that a number of your questions are broad and needing a lot of research to answer. That is probably why you are having a hard time getting answers: you are asking for the implementation of features, and not how to do one specific thing. You'll need to narrow your problems down a lot here, so that they can be answered in (e.g.) Laravel or JS terms, rather than how to build/implement a new UI component.